# Is Perl installed on all Unix boxes?

Tags: c, perl

I want to know whether Perl is installed by default on all  Unix-based operating systems. Since I want to write server-side programs, I need to choose between Perl and C.

Comment: Well, what does "latest UNIX servers" mean?

Comment: Rather than worrying about *all* flavors of Unix, why don't you ask about the flavor(s) that you intend to use?  Perl is highly portable.  Certainly if you come across a Unix distribution that lacks Perl, it can be downloaded and compiled pretty easily.

Comment: @DavidO SunOS 10,AIX,RHEL 5,CENTOS 4,HP-UX. I want my program to run in all the latest version which can be older than 3 years.

Comment: If you can compile a C program for all of those platforms, you can compile Perl for all of them.  In fact, you may find it easier to build Perl on those systems than write your C program portably enough to compile on all of them -- With Perl such portability is a long-standing design goal, and a lot of testing goes into maintaining the portability.

Comment: @DavidO: Perl is not written in portable C, so that's not entirely true. The situation has gotten worse in recent years; modern Perl either cannot be built, or at least is not fully functional, without dynamic module loading, meaning that it may be extremely difficult to use it in any system that's static linked...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether Perl is standard on all Unix server installs. I'm not even sure what that means - a server is a piece of hardware, it doesn't have to come with *any* specific software (not even an OS).

I don't think this should be the deciding factor anyway. You can always compile Perl, or distribute Perl with your program. The factors in choosing a language for your project are:

1) Which languages map well to the domain? Using C for a text processing program would be a mistake, this is where Perl and Python shine (perhaps Ruby also?). Using Perl for your hard real time embedded application would probably be a mistake.

2) What experience do the people on the team have?

3) What skills would you (or your company) like to develop? It might be okay to use a new language if this is something that will give you or your company an edge in the long run. The best example of this would be Ericsson switching to Erlang.

Comment: I thought my point was that it couldn't be defined clearly and that it didn't matter for the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Most linux distros DO include it by default.  However, we got a stack of AIX machines a few months back running AIX 7.1 and none of them have perl installed.

The very, very broad answer is no, you cannot assume that every Linux or Unix system you buy will have Perl installed on it.

Comment: Also 100% accurate.  But that was not the question. :)